# Visual Studio extension - add button to editor's status bar

Tags: ide, statusbar, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2022, visx

I'd like to create an extension to **editor's status bar** in Visual Studio 2022.
By this, I mean line with cursor position and `code cleanup` button.
[image: Editor status bar]

It seems that in previous versions of the IDE, the cursor position was presented in the status bar of the IDE:
[image]

There is plenty of information how to work with IDE's status bar, but I cannot find any example how to tackle editor's status bar. Any hint, article, blog post is highly appreciated.

Comment: Really didn't find an example of how to extend the editor status bar. What function do you want? Maybe there are other ways to do that.

Comment: _"Any hint, article, blog post is highly appreciated."_ - hint: fire up [WPF Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) (it's like a DOM Inspector, but for XAML, including Visual Studio) to get XAML element names and structure info.